# Viewing a dataset with Microsoft Report Viewer

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I have a dataset, which is using a stored procedure to fetch data.
I have filled the dataset and everything is ok. When I am using the debug I can see that the dataset is not empty, but I can't view it with Microsoft Report Viewer.

Here is my code:

```
private void frmPrint_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

    GetCauseMachineMatrixTableAdapter adapter = new GetCauseMachineMatrixTableAdapter();
    QpNibrolDataSet dataset = new QpNibrolDataSet();
    adapter.Fill(dataset.GetCauseMachineMatrix, this.start, this.end);

    DataTable DT = dataset.Tables[0];

    ReportDataSource reportdatasource = new ReportDataSource();
    reportdatasource.Name = "RDS_NAME";
    reportdatasource.Value = DT;

    reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportdatasource);
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
    reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
}
```

the form is saying

> The source of the report definition is not been specified

What am I doing wrong?

I don't use `rdlc` because when I am try to view my dataset, no columns name show; the stored procedure I am using requires parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using RDLC files, what is defining to the ReportViewer control what needs to be rendered on screen?

Comment: But when iam trying to add a datasource to the rdlc file. it shows no columms from the dataset iam using and the dataset requires parameters(stored procedur). Can i do something about it please help.

Comment: You can try to strongly type your datatables.  The inside your dataset, you will have a strongly typed datatable that can be used in the RDLC file.

Answer (score 0):

In your rdlc file you must add dataset, your data name must be "RDS_NAME". first you must pointing your rdlc file.